# WooCommerce template folder not override when add on wordpress child theme

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I'm customizing a Wordpress theme. The original theme has a WooCommerce folder inside like:

```
/wp-content/themes/az/woocommerce/
```

I created a child theme and activated it, then copied the WwooCommerce folder to child theme:

```
/wp-content/themes/az-child/woocommerce/
```

But web when I customized the child theme WooCommerce folder files there was no effect; the site seems to still be using the original WooCommerce folder not the new version.

Could anyone help me resolve this issue, please?

Answer (score 0):

First check whether do you have any overriding template present. for that see the steps in the image given below.

[image]

If there is no templates overridden then refer to [this](https://v4.datafeedr.com/documentation/580) link